# SAS vbs if-statement in automation batch

Tags: sas

i'm working on SAS automation using vb script running on windows cmd,
my question is, how to get LIKE comparision work:

```
For Each objItem in objProjectItems
  If objItem.Name Like "RC%" = True Then 
    'objTasks = objItem.Name.Tasks
  End if
Next
```

**The result is** all comparision get a True except i put

```
A = 123
A = B result is True ! omg
```

**The purpose of this part of code is to get the dynamic object item name then save output as excel** :

```
Set objResults1 = objTasks("Compare Data").Results
Set objResultsR = objResults1("Listing - Compare Data")
objResultsR.SaveAs .....xls
```

THANKS!!

More about the code im using:

```
Dim objProjectItems
Set objProjectItems = prjObject.ProjectItems
```

Comment: You write *VBA Script*. If that VBA or VB-Script?

Comment: What does your question have to do with the programming language SAS?

Comment: What does your second code block `A = 123` `A = B result is True ! omg` have to do with the rest?

Comment: i'm writing vbs, tyring to get the sas project task result from project item. A = 123
A = B result is True  is just a test for the above logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i use instr to search and return positino to get the same purpose:

```
If instr(objItem.Name, "RC_S") = 1 Then
```

Answer (score 0):

The *Like* operator in VBA and VB-Script does not work as the *Like* operator in SQL, nor as regular expressions. It works as described in [described here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swf8kaxw.aspx).

Your code should be

```
For Each objItem In objProjectItems
  If objItem.Name Like "RC*" Then
    'objTasks = objItem.Name.Tasks
  End If
Next
```

(The `= True` is redundant: `objItem.Name Like "RC*"` is a boolean expression which equals `True` if and only if it is true :)

Comment: "objItem.Name Like "RC*" Then" This statement is always getting a true, what wrong with my code?

Comment: I get the impression your problem is not in the part of the code you copied for us.